# Can this be written more elegantly?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if a callback would work with this simple two line jquery below? I'm pretty new so I just am looking to get better :)

Thanks!

```
jQuery('.entry:first').addClass('firstEntry');
jQuery('.entry:first').removeClass('big');
```

Comment: What do you mean with a callback?

Answer (score 6):

```
jQuery('.entry:first').addClass('firstEntry').removeClass('big');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('.entry:first').addClass('firstEntry').removeClass('big');
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery supports chaining...

```
jQuery('.entry:first').addClass('firstEntry').removeClass('big');
```

Also, note there is a [**.toggleClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
jQuery('.entry:first').addClass('firstEntry').removeClass('big');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $entries = $(".entry");
$entries.first().addClass('firstEntry').removeClass('big');
```

or something a bit more readable...

```
var $entries = $(".entry");
$entries
  .first()
    .addClass('firstEntry')
    .removeClass('big');
```

Comment: ok, in this example not really. but when your scanning a massive js file a little formatting can be really nice.